# Integration of $c(y^2)(1-y)^4$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Could anyone please help with integrating $f(y)=cy^2(1-y)^4$? Where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: A tip if you just want to do an integral, use wolfram. If you want to understand it that is a different topic http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intergal+%28y%5E2%29%281-y%29%5E4+with+respect+to+y

Comment: I want to understand how to get you your answer too.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I edited this question assuming $c$ was a constant. Is this correct or is $c(y^2)$ some arbitrary function of $y$? I should have asked this before editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Substitute $u = 1 - y$, giving

$$-c\int (1 - u)^2 u^4 du$$

Now expand $(1 - u)^2$ and integrate term-by-term.

Comment: Let said we integrate from 0 to 1...I found that 1/5*u^5 - 1/3u*6+1/7*u^7 = 1/5-1/3+1/7 = 1/105...did u get the same thing?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Yes, that looks correct (with the case $c = 1$, of course).

Comment: However, I use the method that Jeremy Upsal propose...I got a different answer please look at that as well and let me know what went wrong

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+y^2+%281+-+y%29^4+from+0+to+1) gives $1/105$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$f(y) = cy^2(1-y)^4 = cy^2(1-4y+6y^2-4y^3+y^4) = c(y^2 - 4y^3 + 6y^4 - 4y^5 + y^6)$.

So $\int f(y) = c\int (y^2 + 4y^3 + 6y^4 - 4y^5 + y^6) dy$,

and then you can integrate each part separately.

Comment: is there easy way other than expanding it out

Comment: The [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) is how you would do this if you do not want to use a computer.

Comment: Let said we integrate from 0 to 1...I found that y^3/3+y^4+6/5*y^5+6/5*y^5-4/6*y^6+1/7*y^7 = 211/105...did u get the same thing?

Comment: No I get $\frac{1}{105}$ for $c=1$. This is different because I lost a minus sign at some point. I am fixing it above.